# How to combine these 2 lambdas into a single GroupBy call?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a function like this:

```
 private static  Map<String, ResponseTimeStats> perOperationStats(List<PassedMetricData> scopedMetrics, Function<PassedMetricData, String> classifier)
{
    Map<String, List<PassedMetricData>> operationToDataMap = scopedMetrics.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(classifier));


    return operationToDataMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> StatUtils.mergeStats(e.getValue())));
}
```

Is there any way to have the groupBy call do the transformation that i do explicitly in line 2 so i dont have to separately stream over the map?

**Update**
Here is what `mergeStats()` looks like:

```
public static ResponseTimeStats mergeStats(Collection<PassedMetricData> metricDataList) 
{
    ResponseTimeStats stats = new ResponseTimeStats();
    metricDataList.forEach(data -> stats.merge(data.stats));
    return stats;
}
```

Comment: What does `StatUtils.mergeStats` do?

Comment: i have added `mergeStats` implementation to the question now

Comment: Collectors have to be able to be parallelized, which it doesn't look like you could do with your `mergeStats` implementation as it's written currently, because there's no way to combine two `ResponseTimeStats`.  But you could still use the second approach from my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can rewrite `StatUtils.mergeStats` into a `Collector`, you could just write

```
return scopedMetrics.stream().collect(groupingBy(classifier, mergeStatsCollector));
```

And even if you can't do this, you could write

```
return scopedMetrics.stream().collect(groupingBy(classifier,
    collectingAndThen(toList(), StatUtils::mergeStats)));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, since I'm assuming `mergeStatsCollector` needs all the `PassedMetricData` objects that belong to the same group in order to produce a `ResponseTimeStats`.

Comment: We have no way of telling that, but I wouldn't necessarily assume that -- most types of "merging" should be doable with a `Collector`.

Comment: @Eran: Approach added that would work in one pass even if that was the case.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it might work. +1. If the OP confirms it works, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to group the `PassedMetricData` instances, you must consume the entire Stream since, for example, the first and last `PassedMetricData` might be grouped into the same group.

That's why the grouping must be a terminal operation on the original Stream and you must create a new Stream in order to do the transformation on the results of this grouping.

You could chain these two statements, but it won't make much of a difference :

```
private static  Map<String, ResponseTimeStats> perOperationStats(List<PassedMetricData> scopedMetrics, Function<PassedMetricData, String> classifier)
{
    return scopedMetrics.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(classifier)).entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> StatUtils.mergeStats(e.getValue())));
}
```